# Converting curl to fetch

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch

I can successfully curl an endpoint and get a 200 response, but when I use the curl to fetch converter, the api complains about on of the body params. I don't have any control over the api so I'm not really sure what's going on there.

Here is my successful curl:

```
curl -v -X POST https://someurl -d 'param1=someValue' -d 'param2=somOtherValue'
```

Using https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/, suggests using following body in the fetch request:

```
"param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue"
```

But using that gives me the response:

> Param1 is not valid

Any idea on what the fetch body should look like to make it work just like the curl?

EDIT:

Converting the fetch back to a curl helps to understand the difference.
So, this works:

```
curl -v -X POST https://someurl -d 'param1=someValue' -d 'param2=someOtherValue'
```

But this doesn't:

```
curl -v -X POST https://someurl -d 'param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue'
```

This seems to be the case for this specific api, still I can't change the api so I would like to find the equivalent fetch body for the first curl

Comment: Maybe try just adding the params to the URL: `https://someurl? param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue`, and POST to that URL

Comment: When you give `-d 'param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue'` to CURL, it’s going to send `someValue&param2=someOtherValue` as the value for `param1`. To send multiple params with curl, you need to specify a separate `-d` option for each param. That’s why `-d 'param1=someValue' -d 'param2=someOtherValue'` works and `-d 'param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue'` doesn’t.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: ok, so how do I do this in a javascript fetch? When using the curl to fetch converter and then converting it back to a curl again, I end up with the wrong curl. So what should the fetch body look like?

Comment: `fetch("https://someurl?param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue", {method: "POST"})` is what it would look like. With no request body and no additional request headers needed.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: doesn't -d mean that it is to be sent in the post body?

Comment: Yeah but with curl you can also try just doing `curl -v -X POST https://someurl?param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue`. That sends the POST with no request body and no additional headers.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, just tried it but it's still the same error "param1 not valid"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [this](https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/) to convert curl to fetch:

```
fetch("https://someurl", {
  body: "param1=someValue&m2=somOtherValue",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

**Working snippet**

```js
fetch("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts", {
  body: "param1=someValue&m2=somOtherValue",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  method: "POST"
}).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: See the question. That's exactly what I used but when I try to use the suggested fetch structure that you posted, the api complains about one of the params, as I write in the question

Comment: Ok, so the problem has something to do with how the api handles the request as the suggested solution works with a mocked api

Comment: This is the correct answer. Found out that there was an error on the server side after contacting their support

Answer (score 2):

I use [postman client](https://postman.com) to convert api request between languages.

1. Import -> Raw text (paste your curl command here)

[image]

2. Code -> select your language

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this [online cURL Converter](https://www.kodytools.com/curl-converter) It support multiple programming languages such as python, php, ruby, etc.

Curl Snippet

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
```

Fetch Snippet

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/data", {
    method: "POST",
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        param1: "value1",
        param2: "value2",
    }),
});
```